# I'm unable to add a service reference, 404 error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, odata

I have been trying to get an API to work through "Add Service Reference" and when I put in the address I get an error, I'm wondering if someone could assist me.  Since I'm not fully familiar with APIs and how they should interact,  I do not know if I'm providing enough information, please let me know if you need more.

When I put the web address in a browser it does seem to pull up correctly, the code below is the copy from the 1st line of code through 1 entry for a store.

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://10.1.1.59/assets/api/$metadata#StoreInfo","value":[
    {
      "fHasCC":true,"fHasDG":false,"strP_Addrss":"1471 Center ","strP_City":"Mount ","strP_St":"DC","strP_ZipCd":"99999","strP_Phone":"5558858545","strCurCustPhone":"5556668888","strP_Fax":"5557778888","strMgrLName":"Pr","strMgrFName":"Don","strPropEmail":"S01201@lge.com","fRemoved":false,"strRTLID":"12628","strRVP":"RH","strMarket":"Mount , SC","strPropID":"01201","strFirst":"Je","strLast":"Laus","ARstrFirst":"Ada","ARstrLast":"Cer","strPMFirst":"Sn","strPMLast":"Zi","strTruck":"001","RVPstrFirst":"Ry","RVPstrLast":"Han","strPRFirst":"Sa","strPRLast":"Dn","dtAcq":"1995-06-26T00:00:00-04:00","dtOfcSunCl":"1899-12-30T16:00:00-05:00","dtOfcSunOp":"1899-12-30T12:00:00-05:00","dtOfcSatCl":"1899-12-30T18:00:00-05:00","dtOfcSatOp":"1899-12-30T09:00:00-05:00","dtOfcWdCl":"1899-12-30T18:00:00-05:00","dtOfcWdOp":"1899-12-30T09:00:00-05:00","strAccessHours":"6:00 AM to 9:00 PM","strLunch":"1:00 PM TO 2:00 PM","strRVPEmail":"rhage.com","strAMDEmail":"jlage.com","strAREmail":"acoge.com","strPMEmail":"szom","strPREmail":"sdge.com","dblLat":373,"dblLon":71,"strOwnership":"SALP","intProp":1,"fLge":1,"strHRGeneralist":"kas","fWiFi":false
    },{
```

The error I'm getting is:

> There was an error downloading
>   'http://10.1.1.59/assets/api/StoreInfo/$metadata'. The request failed
>   with HTTP status 404: Not Found. Metadata contains a reference that
>   cannot be resolved: 'http://10.1.1.59/assets/api/StoreInfo/'. There
>   was no endpoint listening at http://10.1.1.59/assets/api/StoreInfo/
>   that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect
>   address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more
>   details. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. If the
>   service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution
>   and adding the service reference again.

Is there something I can do to get this to connect correctly? I'm currently working in a VB.net windows form application.

Thank you

Comment: Would you edit your question to include your service configuration as well. We'll need to see that.

Comment: @InteXX I do apologize, but what exactly is a service configuration, or where would I get it to show you?

Comment: Pardon my delay; yesterday was fraught with distractions. A service can be configured either entirely in code, entirely in your `App.config` file or any combination of both. When you create a WCF service, Visual Studio places the configuration in your `App.config` by default, so it's likely there in your case. Look for everything between and including the `<system.serviceModel>` tags. Sample [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx#code-snippet-2).

Comment: If this is a WebAPI that you're trying to connect to, you can't use a service reference. Service references are for WCF and SOAP. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13746732/722393).